# Generate a excerpt from an ACF-wysiwyg-field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, excerpt

I have an ACF-field, that gives an output like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p><img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-48" src="http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/foo-bar.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="640" /></p>
<p>Sed lacinia enim a <strong>est aliquet</strong>, et accumsan ex pellentesque. </p>
<p>Adipiscing elit, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
```

... Both images and text.

With [wp_html_excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_html_excerpt) I can remove all tags, so I get one long text-blurp.

But with WordPress' native excerpts, then it doesn't remove line-breaks or bold text, which I find nice.

How would I go about achieving, getting an excerpt like that, from my ACF-wysiwyg-field?

So ideally, I would call my function like this: `create_neat_excerpt( $html, 15 );` and get an output like this (from above-given input):

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Sed lacinia enim a <strong>est aliquet</strong>, et accumsan...</p>
```

### Addition: My current attempt

```
$project_desc = get_field( 'project_description' );

if( !empty( $project_desc ) ):
  $trimmed_text = wp_html_excerpt( $project_desc, 800 );
  $last_space = strrpos( $trimmed_text, ' ' );
  $modified_trimmed_text = substr( $trimmed_text, 0, $last_space );
  echo $modified_trimmed_text . '...';
endif;
```

Comment: What kind of native excerpts do you have on mind?

Comment: Like on a regular archives-page, where it shows an excerpt, which by default returns 55 words. Source: [the_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) ... That there removes images, but keeps line-breaks and `<strong>`-tags.

Comment: @Zeth in the source `the_excerpt()` you provided, it actually says "An auto-generated excerpt will also have all shortcodes and tags removed."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide your own implementation of `wp_trim_excerpt` which is responsible for trimming and stripping HTML tags (it uses `wp_strip_all_tags`),

By copying the function source code and applying the change that you want (which is keeping the `<p>` and `<strong>` tags (or any additional tags as you wish) and it will work nicely.

I copied the function for you and applied the change of allowing `<p>` and `<strong>` to be on your final excerpt. **(You should put this code in your `functions.php` file)**

```
function wp_trim_excerpt_modified($text, $content_length = 55, $remove_breaks = false) {
    if ( '' != $text ) {
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = excerpt_remove_blocks( $text );
        $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $num_words = $content_length;
        $more = $excerpt_more ? $excerpt_more : null;
        if ( null === $more ) {
            $more = __( '&hellip;' );
        }
        $original_text = $text;
        $text = preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $text );

        // Here is our modification
        // Allow <p> and <strong>
        $text = strip_tags($text, '<p>,<strong>');

        if ( $remove_breaks )
            $text = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t ]+/', ' ', $text);
        $text = trim( $text );
        if ( strpos( _x( 'words', 'Word count type. Do not translate!' ), 'characters' ) === 0 && preg_match( '/^utf\-?8$/i', get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) ) {
            $text = trim( preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text ), ' ' );
            preg_match_all( '/./u', $text, $words_array );
            $words_array = array_slice( $words_array[0], 0, $num_words + 1 );
            $sep = '';
        } else {
            $words_array = preg_split( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $num_words + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
            $sep = ' ';
        }
        if ( count( $words_array ) > $num_words ) {
            array_pop( $words_array );
            $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
            $text = $text . $more;
        } else {
            $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Notice the line that is doing the stripping:

**Line:22** `$text = strip_tags($text, '<p>,<strong>');`

And your code should be like this:

```
$project_desc = get_field( 'project_description' );
if( !empty( $project_desc ) ):
    $trimmed_text = wp_trim_excerpt_modified( $project_desc, 15 );
    $last_space = strrpos( $trimmed_text, ' ' );
    $modified_trimmed_text = substr( $trimmed_text, 0, $last_space );
    echo $modified_trimmed_text . '...';
endif;
```

For more information, you can checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24160854/4365678) on stackoverflow it is more detailed.

Comment: Awesome. Two things, though: 1) The `remove_breaks` is initially defined in the if-statement. And 2) What does this line do: `if ( strpos( _x( 'words', 'Word count type. Do not translate!' ), 'characters' ) === 0 && preg_match( '/^utf\-?8$/i', get_option( 'blog_charset' ) ) ) {
            $text = trim( preg_replace( "/[\n\r\t ]+/", ' ', $text ), ' ' );`

Comment: @Zeth Yes, this is how wordpress is doing the simple action of getting the excerpt and trimming words. the first one though I copied it and it was a parameter in the function .. but forgot to replace it (with false for example).
About the second one i just copied it so we don't mess anything up. 
I will edit the remove_breaks option to be false by default just as wordpress did it in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

using `apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_field( 'project_description' ) );` is close, but it's missing a vital step in getting you where you want.  the core excerpt builder runs another filter before it hits `the_excerpt`. it's `get_the_excerpt` and on that filter is a call to `wp_trim_excerpt()` which runs `wp_trim_words()`.  if you look at that function you will see it runs `wp_strip_all_tags()` before trimming content to 55 words.  This is the part you are missing to get your content to look like a regular excerpt without any images.  I haven't tested the below but it should work without too much modification needed.

```
$raw_content = get_field( 'project_description' );
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words($raw_content);
$clean_excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', $trimmed_content);

echo $clean_excerpt;
```

Clean that up however you like, I spread it all out for readability.

EDIT:  `wp_trim_excerpt()` only runs all the fun filters if it's pulling from post content.  replaced with `wp_trim_words()`

Comment: Hmm... It still displays everything from the acf-wysiwyg-field.

Comment: interesting.  maybe replace `wp_trim_excerpt()` with a straight up call to `strip_tags()`  of course then you'll need to trim to the word length you want after but if it's not stripping tags inside that function try doing it first?

Comment: just reread `wp_trim_excerpt()`  when you pass it text that function just dumps out what you gave it instead of cleaning up and filtering.  try using `wp_trim_words()` instead.  you may need to pass that through some more filters as well to get it looking right

Comment: Hmm... Now it filters the content (using wp_trim_words). So it trims it to the 55 words and removes images. But it also remove break-lines and `<strong>`-tags. I don't know if it's my memory toying with me that the regular `the_excerpt` actually does that as well. But I'm looking for something that keeps newlines and strong-tags.

Comment: Okay `the_excerpt` removes all that stuff but I'll edit the answer to work around that.  basically you need to dig into the functions called by `wp_trim_words()` until you find the one that takes an argument for tags to ignore, then go back up to trim words and manually apply all the other functions/filters called in that function yourself.

Comment: nevermind, Ibrahim's answer is a perfectly good implementation of what I was going to do.  use that

Answer (score 0):

Use `the_excerpt` filter (see [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_excerpt/))

`apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_field( 'my-wysiwyg-field' ) );`

Comment: I tried it, and I can't get it to work. When I call it from inside the loop, in my `single.php`-file, then it doesn't change anything. Do I need to create a function and put that in my functions.php? Or can you elaborate on, how I'm supposed to use it?

Comment: You should update your question to show the code that you are using (don't add it as a reply as it gets a bit messy). My answer just showed the function, as I don't know how your script handles it, but as a bare minimum, add `echo` to output the filter - `echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_field( 'my-wysiwyg-field' ) );`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the code now. I did try echoing the filter ( `echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $project_desc )`, as you suggested, - but it doesn't change anything (it includes images as well, when echoing it out like that).